# iOS7 App Switcher-style Parallax?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, parallax

I'm trying to create a navigation system similar to the iOS 7 native app switcher - in that I have a set of images along the bottom and a set of views above them, which scroll together, but at different rates.

I understand from a little digging that I need to implement a parallax scrolling effect, but what would be the best way to handle this? Should I set up two `UIScrollView` instances wide enough for the correct number of images/views, then set the contentOffset on one when I scroll the other? Is there a better way to ensure they stay in sync?

Apologies that this is something of a vague question, but specifically I'd like to know if there is a preferred means of implementing parallax while keeping the content in the two portions in sync in terms of both hitting the centre of the display at the same time, etc.

Comment: I think your own answer should work just fine! If the content sizes are different (which they probably are) you have to multiply the offset with some factor k.

Comment: I believe the session on scroll views at WWDC 2013 specifically talked about the app switcher, though I don't recall at the moment what their solution was. Check the [video](http://developer.apple.com/videos)?